# Complex model with arrows and boxes

Tags: boxes, arrows

I hope, anyone could help me with the following.
For my thesis I need two models as you see in the screenshots. The two models should be horizontally aligned with the text.

Thank you in advance!!!

[image: second model]
[image: first model]

Comment: does the answer suit your requirement

Comment: What you try so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Using the `tikz` package and relative positioning of nodes:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}
% first image
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 7mm,
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw, thick,
                 minimum height=5ex, outer sep=1ex},
every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, -{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 3]}}
                    ]
% nodes
\node (n1) [box]                {(1) Branche};
\node (n2) [box,right=of n1]    {(2) Organization};
\node (n3) [box,above right=of n2]  {(3) Mitarbeiter};
\node (n4) [box,below right=of n2]  {(4) Product};
\node (n5) [box,below right=of n3]  {(5) Langlebigeit};
% arrows
\path   (n1) edge (n2) 
        (n1) edge (n3.west)
        (n1) edge (n4.west)
        (n2) edge (n3)
        (n2) edge (n4)
        (n2) edge (n5)
        (n3) edge (n5)
        (n4) edge (n5)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}

% second image
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 4mm and 7mm,
   box/.style = {rectangle, draw, thick,
                 text width=9em, minimum height=5ex, align=center, 
                 outer sep=1ex},
every edge/.style = {draw, semithick, -{Triangle[angle=45:2pt 3]}}
                    ]
% nodes
\node (n1) [box] {Respect Selbswirksamkeit Selbstestimmung Anerkennung Tufridenheit};
\node (n2) [box,above right=of n1]    
                {Umwelt Mitarbeiter Formelle Structure Organisation Organisationsziel};
\node (n3) [box,above right=of n2]  {Organisationtheorie};
\node (n4) [box,right=of n2 -| n3.east] {Organisation};
\node (n5) [box,right=of n1 -| n2.east] {Individium};
\node (n6) [box,below right=of n5.east |- n1.south] {Langlebigeit/Erfolg};
\node (n7) [box,below  left=of n5.west |- n1.south] {Resonanc};
% arrows
\path   (n1) edge (n5)
        (n1) edge (n7)
        (n2) edge (n1)
        (n2) edge (n4)
        (n2) edge (n5)
        (n3) edge (n2)
        (n3) edge (n4)
        (n3) edge (n5)
        (n3) edge (n6)
        (n3) edge (n7)
        (n4) edge (n6)
        (n5) edge (n4)
        (n5) edge (n6)
        (n7) edge (n5)
        (n7) edge (n6)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!! 
I tried to change the code for the second one, but somehow don't manage to place the boxes in the right way. How did you do it for the second model?

Comment: @Julipf, it is evident from provided MWE. Nodes are positioned relative to other nodes. For example, the second node is above right from the first node: `\node (n2) [box,above right=of n1]  {...}`. Distances are determined by `node distance= <vertical distance> and <horizontal distance>`, i.e.: `node distance = 4mm and 7mm,` node `n5` is right from intersection of horizontal line through center of the  node `n1`  and vertical line through east side of the node `n2`, i.e.:  `right=of n1 -| n2.east` . BTW, MWE in answer contains code for both images.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. It is the first time I am using Latex, so having someone explaining me the basics is really helpful. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Does this satisfy the first part of your question -- if yes the same can be modified to the second portion also --- the text in the box can be edited to your choice

[image]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[
    terminal/.style={
        % The shape:
        rectangle,
        % The size:
        minimum size=6mm,
        % The border:
        very thick,
        draw=red!50!black!50, % 50% red and 50% black,
        % and that mixed with 50% white
        % The filling:
        top color=white, % a shading that is white at the top...
        bottom color=red!50!black!20, % and something else at the bottom
        % Font
        font=\itshape
    }]
  

   
    \matrix[row sep=8mm,column sep=12mm] {
        % First row:
        & & \node [terminal](p4) {unsigned integer};& &  & \\
        % Second row:
        \node [terminal](p1) {(1)unsigned integer}; &

        \node [terminal](p2) {unsigned integer}; &

        &
        \node [terminal](p3) {unsigned integer}; \\
        % Third row:
        & & \node [terminal] (p5){unsigned integer};& &  & \\
    };

\draw   (p1) edge [->] (p2)
        (p2) edge [->] (p3);
\draw   (p1) edge [->, shorten >=2pt] (p4.west)
        (p2) edge [->, shorten >=6pt] (p4.west)
        (p1) edge [->, shorten >=2pt] (p5.west)
        (p2) edge [->, shorten >=6pt] (p5.west)
        (p4) edge [->, shorten >=6pt] (p3)
        (p5) edge [->, shorten >=6pt] (p3);     
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Thank you @js bibra for your help!!